# Сверстать правильно slider dots

Tags: javascript, css

Немогу никак правильно сверстать slider dots чтобы получилось так и когда слайдер переключается на следующий зеленая линия передвегалась по белой линии. Использую slider [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Есть идеи как сделать чтобы зеленый border-top как двигался по белой линии?)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предоставьте кусок кода, где происходит проблема.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hx2gwtm0/ - вот )) слайды прыгают, линия не на основной линии) вообщем косяки(( и border-top исчезает и появляется и не бегает по линии(

Comment: @edem https://jsfiddle.net/hx2gwtm0/2/ - надо чтобы зеленые линии были над белым) и как бы передвегалась по нему при переключении слайда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Учился ES6 и где то видел подобную задачу, по быстрому, для себя, накидал  подобное https://jsfiddle.net/ob0hz4ga/1/ думаю не сложно будет переделать на старый js(если нужно) и под вашу задачу...
Понимаю что поздновато с ответом, но вдруг кому пригодится для осознания направления :)
Кусочек кода для того что бы можно было оставить ссылку на jsfiddle.net :

```
 const nav =...
```

Comment: Попробую переделать на jQuery. Ответ кстати хороший) Лучше поздно чем никогда)

Comment: Вырезал из работы 10 минут и переделал по быстрому на JQ (конечно можно оптимизировать/улучшить и тп, но вам нужно решение или направление для понимая :) ) https://jsfiddle.net/ob0hz4ga/3/